# Linked selects for combination of 2 items

Tags: select

I have a set of combinations:

- a vs b
- a vs c
- e vs f
- h vs g
- 100s more ...

I would like "a vs b" to be preselected but stimulate the user to select another interesting combination.

Ideally the user can select something to replace a or b and then immediately see what available options there are to combine the new item with.

[image]

Comment: Is it some kind of a game you are devising ? mobile ? desktop ? we need more context and details to be able to add value. What do you mean by 'new item' ? you mean a combination of a and b is resulting in a new item ?  otherwise we are left to our own interpretations..

Answer (score 1):

There isn't actually any question in your post, which makes this difficult to answer, but I'll have a go anyway.

Can't you just show a list of both, and update the other list anytime there is a change?

[image]

If this causes any confusion, then you can separate the choice from the selection:
[image]